# vercel build incorrectly builds NextJS getServerSideProps

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js13

vercel build converts the NextJS build to optimize for vercel serverless functions. As soon as you add `getServerSideProps` to an page component (eg. `index.page.tsx`), it builds out `next-server` with missing files.

#### Dependencies

"next": "~13.4.12",
"vercel": "31.1.1",
"react": "18.2.0"

`vercel build`

#### Node Runtime

```
// Default on vercel is nodejs runtime
// export const config = {
//     runtime: 'nodejs',
// }

// pages/index.page.tsx
export async function getServerSideProps() {
   return { props: {} }
}

export default function Page() {
   return <div />;
}
```

Result:
[image: .vercel/output/node_modules/server]

```
// .vercel/output/node_modules/server/next-server.js
...
require("./node-environment");
require("./require-hook");
require("./node-polyfill-fetch");
require("./node-polyfill-form");
require("./node-polyfill-web-streams");
require("./node-polyfill-crypto");
const _utils = require("../shared/lib/utils");
...
```

#### Edge Runtime

```
export const config = {
   runtime: 'experimental-edge', // Currently experimental for vercel next
}

// pages/index.page.tsx
export async function getServerSideProps() {
   return { props: {} }
}

export default function Page() {
   return <div />;
}
```

Result:
[image: .vercel/output/index.func]